# Count results on filtered and sorted query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having troubles doing this equivalent in ES:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT current_place
    FROM `request`
    WHERE user_id = '3'
    ORDER BY asked_at DESC
    LIMIT 10
) sr1
WHERE current_place = '4'
```

The goal is to take the 10 most recent records for an user (`asked_at` is a timestamp field), and count how many record have a `current_place = '4'`

In Elasticsearch I did this, without ordering because I didn't even succeed to filter to 10 elements:

```
GET /index/type/_search
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user_id": 3
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "current_place": 4
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Which gives me:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 54,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [
      ... truncated, 10 records ...
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I perform a count on the ordered and filtered data ?

**EDIT:**

Here is a sample of data:

```
1 | 2019-03-13 18:28:17
1 | 2019-01-15 16:48:30
1 | 2019-01-15 16:25:32
1 | 2019-01-15 16:19:36
1 | 2019-01-15 15:43:33
1 | 2019-01-15 15:42:05
4 | 2018-11-22 14:14:03
1 | 2018-09-11 11:36:05
4 | 2018-09-11 11:00:49
1 | 2018-08-31 11:19:17 -> 10th line
1 | 2018-08-31 11:19:17
1 | 2018-08-31 11:09:32
1 | 2018-08-27 10:19:04
4 | 2018-08-23 11:56:27
```

the SQL query returns `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with elasticsearch if you have *n* shards for that particular index.

So basically there is a feature called [`terminate after`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html) which is available with request body search, which would only take into account the *n documents* from each **shard**. Yes, it works on shard level.

Using that, let's say, my index has `5` shards, I thought I can use the value `2` in the below updated query to see if only 10 documents(5 shards * 2 documents) are retrieved but it doesn't work that way as one shard might return only `1` document while rest return `2`, where I ultimately ended up with apply aggregation query on 9 documents.

Again with that less documents from each shard, your sorted result itself may not fetch the correct top 10 documents.

### Aggregation Query

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "size":0,
   "terminate_after":2,
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "filter":[  
            {  
               "term":{  
                  "user_id":101
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "sort":[  
      {  
         "asked_at":{  
            "order":"desc"
         }
      }
   ],
   "aggs":{  
      "filter_current_place":{  
         "filter":{  
            "term":{  
               "current_place":4
            }
         },
         "aggs":{  
            "requiredCount":{  
               "value_count":{  
                  "field":"current_place"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Below is how my response appeared:

### Response

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "terminated_early" : true,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 9,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "filter_current_place" : {
      "doc_count" : 2,
      "requiredCount" : {
        "value" : 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that the hits are only `9` despite mentioning that I would want 2 documents to be considered from each shard. Of course the count appeared correct because as mentioned in the question, the 9th document has `current_place:4`. What if this was in 10th position!!

> This is probably not correct and pretty clearly which is something 
>   that would require to be done at the client side or service layer.

If that is the case, then you would only need the below query and handle the logic of aggregating based on top 10 documents on client side/service layer.

### Sorted Query

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "size":10,
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "filter":[  
            {  
               "term":{  
                  "user_id":101
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "sort":[  
      {  
         "asked_at":{  
            "order":"desc"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

**Note:** The only possible way to achieve this via Elasticsearch using the first query I've mentioned above is that your index has only a `single shard` and you make use of `"terminate_after":10`

Although technically this doesn't, I hope this helps!

Comment: What I understand is that your bucket script caps the result to 10. But it doesn't calculate on the 10 most recent items. See my edit for a sample data. Your query returns 10 (actually, i've troncated the dataset in my edit)

Comment: @LaurentW. Please check the answer. I've updated it accordingly based on your requirement.